# Serialization issue with entity framework and sql session state

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, session, serialization

I have this entity and dbcontext on my application:

```
[Serializable, Table("calc.Student")]
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public StudentDbContext() : base("name=DefaultConnection") 
{ 

}

public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
}
```

My DTO class:

```
[Serializable]
public class StudentDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

My api controller:

```
public IQueryable<StudentDTO> Get()
{
    var students = from b in db.Students
                   select new StudentDTO()
                   {
                       Id = b.Id
                   };
    return students ;
}
```

Now my problem here is with my session state. On my web.config file, I stated the code below so I can store my session on the database:

```
<sessionState mode="SQLServer" allowCustomSqlDatabase="true" cookieless="false"
```

With this line of code, I am receiving this error:

> Unable to serialize the session state. In 'StateServer' and
>   'SQLServer' mode, ASP.NET will serialize the session state objects,
>   and as a result non-serializable objects or MarshalByRef objects are
>   not permitted. The same restriction applies if similar serialization
>   is done by the custom session state store in 'Custom' mode.

I thought returning a DTO object would resolve my problem but now I am stuck.

Any ideas?

Comment: Not entirely sure how the api call is related to your *session state* based on this code - however, you might have some luck changing it to return `List<StudentDTO>` instead of `IQueryable<StudentDTO>`

Comment: Also classes with EF proxies are serializable (with eagerly load) so you should not need a DTO object. Like Rob said, looking this code the problem could be IQueryable<>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot to provide my answer to my problem here but in case others are having the same problem.

The cause is this line below on my `StudentRepository` class.

```
StudentDbContext context = new StudentDbContext();
```

Even though the `StudentRepository` has a signature of `[Serializable]`, it has member which can't be serialized.

The fix is to only declare the context inside the methods.

```
public IEnumerable<Student> GetAllStudent()
{
    using (var context = new StudentDbContext())
    {

    }
}
```

No need to use the `DTO object`.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with EF. As stated it the error that you're showing the problem is that you'¡re trying to store an object in `Session` which cannot be serialized or is a `MarshalByRef` object.

You need to find the offending `Session["xyz"] = myObject;` and make the class of `myObject` serializable.

Besides, you need to configure your server to allow SQL Server Session State: [HOW TO: Configure SQL Server to Store ASP.NET Session State](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/317604#bookmark-3). Just in case you didn't it.

Please, follow the link in this comment from [Session-State Modes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586.aspx):

> Objects stored in session state must be serializable if the mode is SQL Server. For information on serializable objects, see the [SerializableAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serializableattribute.aspx) class.